# Angular 2 drag and drop ngx-dnd missing styles

Tags: css, angular

I am using 'swimlane/ngx-dnd' for performing drag and drop of a accordion items. I have done a npm install and included the NgxDnDModule to application module, as per https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-dnd#install

The drag and drop events are working but the styling seems to be missing to indicate the drag/drop events.

Does anyone know what .css file needs to be included in angular-cli.json..?

Answer (score 2):

I have used `ng2-dnd`, so according to uses of that library I think these css files can be included in angular-cli.json

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-dnd/release/index.css",
    "../node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-dnd/release/components/container/container.component.css",
    "../node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-dnd/release/components/item/item.component.css"
]
```